# How to create and update Markers in batch in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, markers

I have thousands of markers for a file which I am highlighting with custom annotations.

However, after adding listener in my eclipse project, I found that every time a marker is created, it refreshes the GUI and therefore calls my listener (IResourceChangeListener). That means, my listener is called for 1000 times for 1000 markers. So far  there is no performance issue (less than 2 seconds) but I think this situation will be different if I have 10000 markers or more.

Is it possible to create all these markers in a batch so that it doesnt refresh the GUI everytime and will call my listener only once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the changes batched up in to fewer events by using one of the workspace modify classs.

`WorkspaceJob` is an extension of `Job` that will batch the changes done during the Job.

`WorkspaceModifyOperation` is an `IRunnableWithProgress` which you can run with a progress monitor dialog or anything that supports runnable with progress such as a wizard container or the `IProgressService`.

Comment: One interesting thing is, I already kept my marker creation/deletion code under the WorkspaceJob. But for different purpose, to run my codes after listener unlock the workspace. So, I was already batching and probably this was a reason that the plugin was creating 1000 markers without any delay. But I didn't know that it called batching. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation`to "lock" the workspace. After the execution you'll get only one ResourceDelta.

```
ProgressMonitorDialog pmdialog = new ProgressMonitorDialog(
        activeShell);
pmdialog.run(true, true,new WorkspaceModifyOperation() {

    @Override
    protected void execute(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException,
            InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
        // create all my markers here

    }
});
```